# Php print array to comma separated, quoted txt file

Tags: php, arrays, fopen

I have an array like this

```
$rowArray = array(
    array(
        "http://www.website.com/article.html",
        "09/18/2013",
        "An article about stuff"
    ),
    array(
        "http://www.google.com",
        "09/18/2013",
        "The Google",
    )
);
```

I want to make a .txt file like this:

```
http://www.website.com/article.html,09/18/2013,"An article about stuff"\r\n
http://www.google.com,09/18/2013,"The Google"\r\n
```

Notice the "quotes" around strings with spaces and commas and also the \r\n return.

I've tried this: (I set the headers else where and their fine)

```
$op = fopen("php://output", "w"); 

foreach($rowArray AS $row) {
    $row[] = "\r\n";
    fputcsv($op, $row);
}

fclose($op);
```

And this

```
$row[] = "\r\n";
fwrite($op, implode(",",$row));
```

And this

```
echo mb_convert_encoding(implode(",", $row) . "\r\n", 'UTF-8');
```

I need to convert it because I have characters scraped from the web in my database and it needs to be UTF-8 for the text editor. Can anyone help me? I cant seem to get the double quotes and the \r\n and the "quotes". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach ($rowArray as $row){
    $row[2] = '"' . $row[2] . '"';
    fwrite($op, implode(',', $row) . "\r\n");
}
```

http://codepad.org/XBUVbbN0

Answer (score 0):

Ok heres what I needed

- Character encoding to UTF-8
- Line endings of \r\n
- Double quotes around strings with spaces or commas so it doesn't break the csv format (even though Im saving it as a txt file)

What I ended up doing was rewriting the fputcsv function. I only changed three lines and I left comments below so you can see what I changed.

```
protected function _putcsv(&$handle, $fields = array(), $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"') {
    $str = '';
    $escape_char = '\\';
    // I changed $value to $valueRaw so I could convert it easily
    foreach ($fields as $valueRaw) {
        // I added this line to convert to UTF-8 to set the $value variable
        $value = mb_convert_encoding($valueRaw, 'UTF-8');
        if (strpos($value, $delimiter) !== false ||
                strpos($value, $enclosure) !== false ||
                strpos($value, "\n") !== false ||
                strpos($value, "\r") !== false ||
                strpos($value, "\t") !== false ||
                strpos($value, ' ') !== false) {
            $str2 = $enclosure;
            $escaped = 0;
            $len = strlen($value);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
                if ($value[$i] == $escape_char) {
                    $escaped = 1;
                } else if (!$escaped && $value[$i] == $enclosure) {
                    $str2 .= $enclosure;
                } else {
                    $escaped = 0;
                }
                $str2 .= $value[$i];
            }
            $str2 .= $enclosure;
            $str .= $str2 . $delimiter;
        } else {
            $str .= $value . $delimiter;
        }
    }
    $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
    // I changed the string ending from just "\n" to "\r\n"
    $str .= "\r\n";
    return fwrite($handle, $str);
}
```

Problem solved. Thanks for the answers!